# How to ensure a single append data-indepent?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a section where using transitions I fake a computation and put a message "Please wait ... computing" sort of thing.

```
<!-- in the html -->
<body>
  <svg width="1700" height="650"/>
</body>

// js code
var svg = d3.select('svg');

// then somewhere later 
var computingG = svg.append("g")
   .attr("id", "computingId");

computingG.append("text")                
   .attr("y", height / 2)
   .attr("x", width  / 2)
   .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
   .attr('font-family', 'arial')
   .attr('fill', 'black')
   .attr('stroke', 'black')
   .attr('font-size', 30)
   .text("Please wait ... computing");

// and further later
svg.selectAll('#computingId').remove();
```

But I see the text is being created many times on top of each other instead of only once (I see many `g` created and the text is very aliased) ... why is that? I intended this to be a one of text annotation and not data-depending.

[image: generated text]

**UPDATE** I see there are many appended ... how can I prevent many `g` from being appended to that selection?

[image]

Comment: The image looks more like text with a black stroke, what does it look like without the stroke?

Comment: @MatthewPage Oh yes you were right :D

Comment: Woohooo I got one :)

Comment: It is funny still looks aliased but it is much better